# flutter web, Text abnormally cropped

Tags: flutter, web, text, flutter-web

I'm using a `Text` widget inside a `Column` widget. Depending on the user language preference, this text is rather in *English* or in *Thai*. In English I don't have any problem while in Thai for some reason the text in vertically (bottom) cropped:

English version:

[image]

Thai version:

[image]

My code looks like:

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  translation(
                      'You are a tire wholesaler in Thailand and you want to list your products on WYZauto? Let\'s talk!',
                      _languageCode),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[500],
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Text(translation('Line Us', _languageCode),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'JosefinSans',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.orange)),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),

               .....
             ])
```

It only happens in Web, no issue on Android

Answer (score 0):

It does not have enough space to show the text completely, as mobile devices have more space vertically while the web has horizontally, use `Flex` or something else to dynamically give the spaces between widgets instead of `SizedBox`, that should work for both web and mobile and hopefully fix the issue at hand.